# error Multiplying elements of one list by another

Tags: python

Given two lists of integers, write a function multLists(list1, list2) that multiplies each value of the list1 by the values of list2 and returns list1 with it's updated values.

```
def multLists(list1, list2):
    for i in range(len(list1)):
        list1 = list1[i] * list2[i]
    return list1

length = int(input())
first_list = []
second_list = []
for i in range(length):
    num1 = int(input())
    num2 = int(input())
    first_list.append(num1)
    second_list.append(num2)
list1 = multLists(first_list, second_list)
for i in list1:
    print(i)
```

When submitting, this is what occurs:

```
2
1
2
3
4
Your output
Traceback (most recent call last):


     File "main.py", line 17, in <module>
    list1 = multLists(first_list, second_list)
  File "main.py", line 3, in multLists
    list1 = list1[i] * list2[i]
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Your output does not contain
[8, 24]
```

Answer (score 1):

In the line `list1 = list1[i] * list2[i]`, you are setting `list1` (which is a list) to the result of `list1[i] * list2[i]`, which is a number. Maybe you meant `list1[i] = list1[i] * list2[i]`?